# Awk: count occurrence of each character for every column and write it in define order

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I need to count occurence of each character in every column.
My input looks like:

```
0 H B
0 G G
0 B b
0 T G
0 0 T
```

And output should looks like:

```
1 H=0 G=0 I=0 B=0 b=0 T=0 0=5
2 H=1 G=1 I=0 B=1 b=0 T=1 0=1
3 H=0 G=1 I=0 B=1 b=1 T=2 0=0
```

I tried to modify script from [Unix&Linux forum](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/244793-solved-awk-count-occurrence-each-character-every-field.html)

```
awk -F " " '
BEGIN{
cond=1
}
{      
if(cond == 1) {
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        a[i " " "H"]=0
        a[i " " "G"]=0
        a[i " " "I"]=0
        a[i " " "B"]=0
        a[i " " "b"]=0
        a[i " " "T"]=0
        a[i " " "0"]=0
    }
    cond=0
}
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    a[i " " $i]++
}
}
END {  
for(x in a) print x " " a[x]
}'  INPUT_FILE  |

awk '
{
a[$1] = (a[$1] == "" ? $1 : a[$1]) " " $2 "=" $3
    if(max < $1) max = $1
}
END {  
for(i = 1; i <= max; i++) print a[i]
}'
```

but the in output file starts predominantly with 0 instead H.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am not familiar with awk...

Comment: your output is not correct? why last line `T=2` but `G=1`? In 3rd col, there are two `G`s.

Comment: Kent: My mistake, sorry. Should be G=2 and T=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk script produces the output that you want:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{c["H"];c["G"];c["I"];c["B"];c["b"];c["T"];c["0"]}
       {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)++a[i,$i]}
       END{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
           printf "%s ",i;
           for(j in c)printf "%s=%d ",j,a[i,j];print ""}}' file.txt
1 B=0 G=0 T=0 H=0 b=0 I=0 0=5
2 B=1 G=1 T=1 H=1 b=0 I=0 0=1
3 B=1 G=2 T=1 H=0 b=1 I=0 0=0
```

Initialise the array `c` in the BEGIN block so that it contains a key for every character. Loop through every field in each line. Increment the value of the array `a` whose key comprises of the field number and the character in the field. Once every record has been processed, loop through the fields and the keys of the array `c`, printing the counts in the array `a`.

The keys in an array are not ordered, so when you use a `for x in y` loop, you cannot rely on a specific ordering of the output. If you would like to print the keys in a certain order, you would have to specify that yourself. For example, you could do something like this:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)++a[i,$i]}
       END{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
           printf "%s ",i
           printf "H=%d ",  a[i,"H"]
           printf "G=%d ",  a[i,"G"]
           printf "I=%d ",  a[i,"I"]
           printf "B=%d ",  a[i,"B"]
           printf "b=%d ",  a[i,"b"]
           printf "T=%d ",  a[i,"T"]
           printf "0=%d\n", a[i,"0"]
       }}' file.txt
```

Comment: Your script works:] I tried to solved it with another awk script to change column order, but your solutions is smoother :) Thanks A LOT!